# Chartkick column - data not displaying as bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

New to Chartkick and not sure where I'm going wrong. I have a table of tanks, with an attribute of level, and I want to display the tank level as the bar in each chart.

Tank table from schema:

```
create_table "tanks", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.decimal "level"
  t.bigint "zipcode"
  t.bigint "tank_company_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["tank_company_id"], name: "index_tanks_on_tank_company_id"
end
```

Tanks controller:

```
def index
  @tanks = Tank.all
end
```

View:

```
<div class="container text-center tanks-list">
  <div class="row">
    <% @tanks.each do |tank| %>
      <div class="col-md-4 tank">
        <p>Company: <%= tank.tank_company.name %></p>
        <p>Tank ID: <%= tank.id %></p>
        <p>Level: <%= tank.level.to_i %>%</p>
        <%= column_chart tank.level.to_i, min: 0, max: 100 %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

How it's showing up in Chart, but no bars in the graph:

[image: Chart, but no bars in the graph]

Answer (score 0):

your input to column_chart must have keys and values, for example tank_company.id as keys and level as values

```
div class="container text-center tanks-list">
  <div class="row">
    <% @tanks.each do |tank| %>
      <div class="col-md-4 tank">
        <p>Company: <%= tank.tank_company.name %></p>
        <p>Tank ID: <%= tank.id %></p>
        <p>Level: <%= tank.level.to_i %>%</p>
        <%= column_chart @tanks.group(:id).sum(:level), min: 0, max: 100 %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. What I am trying to do is display each tank's level individually as a single bar within a single graph, not all the tanks together in one graph.

Comment: ok, I just edited my answer probably can work with what you want

Comment: I would like to accept your answer and give you the points, but this produces the following error: 

"PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 1: SELECT SUM("tanks"."level") AS sum_level, 1 AS 1 FROM "tanks...
                                                       ^
: SELECT SUM("tanks"."level") AS sum_level, 1 AS 1 FROM "tanks" GROUP BY 1"

Comment: I am familiar with how databases work, just not Chartkick. I wish Chartkick had better documentation for specific use cases. The examples on their site are helpful if your use case follows their idea of how the gem would be used, but not really otherwise.

Comment: my mistake it should be .group(:id) not group(tank.id) since it's inside one table, I just changed my answer

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/a/pREQV) is what that code outputs to the view. It still has every tank in the chart rather than just the specific tank within the each loop.